# Regex/Shell - how to match all except those with specific pattern

Tags: regex, shell

I need a regex in shell to match all strings except those with specific pattern.

My specific pattern can be variable, i.e. (i|I)[2 digits numbers](u|U)[2 digits numbers] in every string should not match.

For example :

Some.text.1234.text => should match
Some.text.1234.i10u20.text => shouldn't match
Some.text.1234.I01U02.text => shouldn't match
Some.text.1234.i83U23.text => shouldn't match

Comment: Did you mean i instead of t? You could select the strings that do not match `[Ii][0-9][0-9][uU][0-9][0-9]`

Comment: You mention `shell`, what tool are you using to run the regex? Please share the relevant code.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, my bad, yes I mean i instead of t.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I use regex in shell script (bash) to match files in a folder

Comment: Please add the relevant script part to the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew

#!/bin/bash

files=`ls`
regex="^(?!.*[tuTU]\d{2}).*$"

for f in $files
do
    if [[ $f =~ $regex ]]
 then
  echo $f
 fi
done

Comment: Ok, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66244653/3832970), it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with that:

```
^(?!.*[tuTU]\d{2}).*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qR3PVp/1)

Explanation:

1. `^` start of a line
2. `?!.*` negative look ahead
3. `[tuTU]\d{2}` check if there exists such character following 2 digits only
4. `.*$` if previous condition is negative then match entire string to end of string `$`

Answer (score 0):

The Bash script checking if a string matches a regex or not can look like

```sh
f='It_is_your_string_to_check';
if [[ "${f^^}" =~ I[0-9]{2}U[0-9]{2} ]]; then
  echo "$f is invalid";
else
   echo "$f is valid"
fi;
```

Here, `"${f^^}"` turns the string into uppercase (so as not to use `(U|u)` and `(I|i)`), and then `=~` operator triggers a regex check here since the pattern on the right side is not quoted. You may play it safe and define the regex pattern with a separate single-quoted string variable and use

```sh
rx='I[0-9]{2}U[0-9]{2}'
if [[ "${f^^}" =~ $rx ]]; then ...
```

See a [Bash demo online](https://ideone.com/EwZxUm):

```sh
s='Some.text.1234.text
Some.text.1234.i10u20.text
Some.text.1234.I01U02.text
Some.text.1234.i83U23.text'
for f in $s; do
  if [[ "${f^^}" =~ I[0-9]{2}U[0-9]{2} ]]; then
    echo "$f is invalid";
  else
     echo "$f is valid"
  fi;
done;
```

Output:

```sh
Some.text.1234.text is valid
Some.text.1234.i10u20.text is invalid
Some.text.1234.I01U02.text is invalid
Some.text.1234.i83U23.text is invalid
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.
Now I would like to capture Some.text and 1234 apart. How can I do that ?

Comment: @emmto I do not know your exact requirements for this. Try `extractrx='(.+)\.([0-9]+)\.[^.]+$'` and then `if [[ "$f" =~ $extractrx ]]; then echo "Result: '${BASH_REMATCH[1]}' and '${BASH_REMATCH[2]}'"`, see [the online demo](https://ideone.com/1tcqER).